# Function accepts const char * but I need to pass it a char*

Tags: c, char, constants, aiff

There is this function in the LibAIFF library:

```
AIFF_Ref AIFF_OpenFile(const char* name, int flags);
```

It accepts a `const char*` but for my use, name has to be of type a `char*` because I need to build it based on the location of my AIFF file on my directory (which I can properly accomplish) - specifically, in my case name is the AIFF file path.

But I think I'm running into some problems because of this (I'm not sure though). What happens when I send the function a `char*`? The bad behavior I'm noticing occurs with an associated `AIFF_CloseFile` function which runs into some problems what seems to be randomly based on the file path I send to it. For example, if I have the exact same AIFF file with two names with just one of the letters changed, the error (which has to do with `AIFF_CloseFile` trying to free a buffer defined within a structure which has either already been freed or hasn't been allocated) occurs with one of them but not the other. If I comment out the call to the close file function, everything works in that the AIFF file is successfully opened and read but I'm not supposed to do that.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The ``const`` only means that ``AIFF_OpenFile()`` promises not to change the input string, that is not your problem. Try asking a new question, include the code in question and a more detailed examples of what goes wrong, and give it a sensible title ("Crashes in AIFF_CloseFile()" or whatever).

Comment: That was useful information. Thanks. Unfortunately, there are many functions involved that are related to the problem I'm facing and I don't quite know how I could ask the question.

Comment: Open your source file in a text editor, select the relevant portion of the code, copy to the Stack Overflow question textbox. Add explanation what goes wrong, with specific examples (input text file names, what exactly the error is, ...). Ideally, include a traceback from your debugger, showing where the error comes from.

Comment: Within this particular library, the `name` argument is only used to create a handle with `fopen()`; perhaps somewhere down the line your `AIFF_Ref` gets partially overwritten by another piece of code.

Comment: @ChristianAichinger and Jack: I have posted a much expanded version of my main question in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451558/libaiff-closefile-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-occurs-randomly) if you'd be willing to take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is fine to use a `char *` when a `const char *` is expected.

If a function accepts a `const char *` it just means that the function won't be changing the string contents at all.

The other way around is not good though.

EDIT:

I don't know the library you are using.. It could be a problem if the library is remembering the string you used, but is not making its own internal copy. This would be an awful library though..

Comment: Ok thanks. That's what I thought. The problem must be elsewhere then.